# Check the kind of a variable in Swift (is it class or struct or enum)

Tags: swift, class, struct, enums, casting

Is it possible in Swift to check the kind of a variable; I want find out if it is a class, a struct or an enum. The variable is of Any type.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you ever need this? I can't think of how this could be used.

Comment: @Alexander It's a one-time and non-production need. Printing some data and formatting it depending on their kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mirror`:

```
Mirror(reflecting:var).displayStyle == .struct
Mirror(reflecting:var).displayStyle == .class
```

Comment: displayStyle returns nil it the type is a String. It should return a struct